# Swift - Crash when try to get JSON values for second time

Tags: json, xcode, swift, nsmutablearray

I am trying to get an array of values from a JSON file using Swift. I found the way to get the values printed when a button is pressed using a IBAction method.

The Function is printing the array fine the first time the button is pressed however, if I press the button again the app crashes giving the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)

The array that I get the first time from printing jsonResult looks Like:

```
1: {
        Age = 30;
        Email = "info@example.com";
        Location = Rome;
        MyText = "Design Agency";
        Name = Admin;
        Password = 123456;
        REF = 002;
        "Reg_Date" = "2015-07-28";
        Sex = Male;
        Surname = "Mobile App"; } 
2: {
        Age = 30;
        Email = "example@gmail.com";
        Location = London;
        MyText = "aaaaaaaaa";
        Name = Andrew;
        Password = 123456;
        REF = 001;
        "Reg_Date" = "2015-07-28";
        Sex = Male;
        Surname = Nos; }
```

It seems that the second time I call the function, it cannot read the file anymore.
Whats wrong with my code? Do I need to close the connection?

```
 @IBAction func login_button(sender: AnyObject) {

            searchFunction()
        }

        func searchFunction() {
            var tempUrlValue = loginJsonResults.stringForKey("loginJsonResults")
            let urlPath: String = "https://example.com/iOS/users_result.json"
            var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
            var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
            var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!
            connection.start()



        }

        func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){
        self.data.appendData(data)
    }

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
        var err: NSError
        var jsonResult: NSMutableArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSMutableArray


        //Call jsonResult Values
        var temporaryString: AnyObject = jsonResult[1]

        for (index, jsonResult) in enumerate(jsonResult){
            println("\(index + 1): \(jsonResult)")
            countUsers++
        }
        println(countUsers)
    }
```

Comment: When you get the JSON the second time, are you supposed to get a different result?

Comment: @dannybess. Yes if another user is registered. Otherwise the file has the same result

Comment: Usually this error occurs when the request does not go through. Do you have some kind of error log server side?

Comment: Cannot see any error.. don't have a error log

Comment: Also the file if I go back to main viewcontroller e open again the viewcontroller with son function I can press the button